# coffeescript + nodejs: caching the compiled server-side javascript using require

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm running a node web server via "coffee my_server.coffee", and I load dependencies via

```
 require './my_library.coffee'
```

My codebase is pretty big, and it's starting to take a significant amount of time for my server to start up, which I believe is due to coffeescript compilation... when I convert the entire thing to javascript, it loads much faster.

What's the least painful way of caching the compiled javascript, so that when I restart my server it only compiles files that I've edited since I last started it?  Ideally it would be totally transparent... I just keep on requiring the coffeescript and it gets cached behind the scenes.

Alternatively, I could run "node my_server.js", and have a watcher on my directory that recompiles coffeescript whenever I edit it, but I don't really like this idea because it clutters up my directory with a bunch of js files, makes my gitignore more complicated, and means I have to manage the watcher function.  Is there a way for me to have my cake (running the "coffee" executable and requiring coffee files) and eat it too (fast load times)?

Comment: Just a note you can do `require './my_library'` without the file extension and it will look for .js, .coffee, and .json files. I recommend omitting the file extension. It will also help with module caching at runtime as the path passed to `require` is the key used to cache modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you don't want to "clutter up your directory with a bunch of .js files", I think you're SOL. If you don't store the .js files on disk ever, you need to compile .coffee to javascript on the fly every time. The `coffee` command to my knowledge does not do any comparison of mtime between the `.js` and `.coffee` files, although in theory it could, in which case leaving the `.js` files around could help your situation. Given your preferences, the only thing that I can suggest is:

- run a watcher that builds all your .coffee files into a separate `build` subdirectory tree
- start your app with `node build/app.js` instead of coffee
- ignore the `build` directory in your `.gitignore`

You'll have to give up on running things via `coffee` though. Curious to see if others have better suggestions. My projects don't suffer from the startup time issue. SSDs and small projects help to keep that short and not annoying.

Comment: I agree with pretty much all of this. My experiences with coffeescript have largely been paired with [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), which with a [coffeescript plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) can allow you to pretty easily automate compilation (and even concatenation) to javascript. I also find having the compiled code to be very helpful for testing. You can ignore these compiled files in version control to keep repo clutter down.